# Most efficient way to signal consumer thread from multiple producer threads using condition variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, race-condition, condition-variable

I have N work threads that does a calculation that one other consumer thread is waiting for.
I am doing this with a condition_variable (CV) and an atomic counter that starts at N, each worker decreases it and the one reaching 0 signals the consumer using the CV.
According to mutiple sources ([example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)), the "shared variable" (the counter in my case) needs to be modified while holding the mutex. You can thereafter signal the CV after releasing the mutex.

I could do this, but it would mean each worker thread will try to aquire the mutex which may cause undesired contention. I'd like to do the decrement without the mutex (since its atomic that should not be a race condition), and only aquire the mutex for the last worker thread, the one actually sending the signal.

Working example:

```
constexpr int N_WORKERS = 10;

struct WorkData
{
    int input[N_WORKERS];
    int result[N_WORKERS];
    std::atomic<int> remainingWorkers;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mutex;  
};

void workerFunc(WorkData* wd, int index)
{
    // Do some calculation here
    wd->result[index] = wd->input[index] * wd->input[index];
    //-------------------------
    if (--wd->remainingWorkers == 0)
    {
        wd->mutex.lock();
        wd->mutex.unlock();
        
        wd->cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    WorkData wd;
    wd.remainingWorkers.store(N_WORKERS);

    std::thread workerThreads[N_WORKERS];
    for (int i = 0; i < N_WORKERS; i++)
    {
        wd.input[i] = i;
        wd.result[i] = 0;
        workerThreads[i] = std::thread(workerFunc, &wd, i);
    }
    // Wait for the worker threads to finish unless they already have
    if (wd.remainingWorkers.load() > 0)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(wd.mutex);
        while (wd.remainingWorkers.load() > 0)
            wd.cv.wait(lock);
    }
    // Consume result of calculations
    for (int i = 0; i < N_WORKERS; i++)
        std::cout << wd.input[i] << "^2 = " << wd.result[i] << std::endl;
    
    for (std::thread& t : workerThreads)
        t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I know I still need to aquire the mutex from the singalling thread in order to ensure the signal isnt sent between the points where the waiting thread checks the atomic and where it enters the condition variable wait, but I see no reason why the worker thread cant modify the counter before aquiring the mutex?

Is this safe, or is there a race condition here that I have missed?

Comment: <<"shared variable" (the counter in my case) needs to be modified while holding the mutex>> - not true, your counter is atomic so no additional synchronization is required. in the documentation "shared variable" refers to condition_variable itself.

Comment: @pptaszni i think the question refers to the result data, not the mutex. The result data is shared across threads, and not modified inside a critical section. The question is more about if locking and unlock a mutex (within any operations inbetween) makes sure the writes to the result will be visible in the main thread.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier 
I think this is the most efficient.

Comment: @pptaszni the atomic variable doesn't require a mutex but the condition variable does otherwise when the consumer does `lock mutex, check value, wait condition` the value can change and a notify be issued between checking the value and waiting on the condition, leading to the wait never completing. e.g. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable "Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified while owning the mutex to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread"

Comment: Read up on reader-writer locks too (std::shared_mutex) this might help. In the end you need to check using a profiler if locking is even your biggest bottleneck, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: And yes you still have an issue, you wait for a condition variable without predicate so you can experience spurious wakeups.

Comment: Spurious wake-ups are handled fine here with the while loop, so that's not a problem (although predicate style is generally preferred).

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah, for that second issue with small window between check and wait I wanted to suggest `cv.wait` with the predicate (and preferably some timeout), which is always recommended over simple `wait` anyway. But I see there already is an answer to the problem.

Comment: Note however that this currently doesn't achieve much more than moving the join loop above the consume step. Also, if you're really worried about contention, you should group your data into at least whole cache lines to avoid false sharing between threads

Comment: @useless This is a minimal working example to illustrate signalling/waiting in producer/consumer threads. The actual input/output processing is for illustrative purposes only

Comment: Re, "It would mean each worker thread will try to aquire the mutex which may cause undesired contention." If the "producer" threads are doing significant work, and if each one only keeps the mutex locked just long enough to decrement the counter, then the chance of any of them finding the mutex locked is _extremely_ small. If the run-time library that you're using is any good, then the cost of locking an uncontested mutex also will be extremely small.

Comment: @SolomonSlow a small chance repeated enough times will happen. In the situation I am looking at, this pattern occurs several hundreds of times per second, and the overall cpu load is high, meaning that yielding can cause long delays (milliseconds) until the thread is scheduled again.
If one of the worker threads does find the mutex locked, it may put the thread to sleep. That delay will delay the cv.notify_one(), which in turn will delay the time until the waiter (which is in the critical path for me) is woken up.
So if possible I want to avoid it

Comment: @pptaszni 
That loop around the wait is equivalent to the cv.wait with the predicate (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait). The reason I wrote it out is to better see and reason about where the counter is acessed and where the lock is held.
Using the predicate version wont help with the issue of the risk of the cv being notified in between the check and the wait().

Answer (score 4):

There is a race condition as the notification can be raised between `wd.remainingWorkers.load() > 0)` and `wd.cv.wait(lock);`. This would lead to `wait` never completing as the notification would be missed. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable which states:

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified while owning the mutex to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

You can remove the mutex contention by separating the remaining worker count and the fact that the work is complete. That way only the worker that completes the last calculation needs to lock the mutex and raise the notification:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int N_WORKERS = 10;

struct WorkData
{
    int input[N_WORKERS];
    int result[N_WORKERS];
    std::atomic<int> remainingWorkers;
    bool complete;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mutex;  
};

void workerFunc(WorkData* wd, int index)
{
    // Do some calculation here
    wd->result[index] = wd->input[index] * wd->input[index];
    //-------------------------
    if (--wd->remainingWorkers == 0)
    {
        wd->mutex.lock();
        wd->complete = true;
        wd->mutex.unlock();
        
        wd->cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    WorkData wd;
    wd.remainingWorkers.store(N_WORKERS);
    wd.complete = false;

    std::thread workerThreads[N_WORKERS];
    for (int i = 0; i < N_WORKERS; i++)
    {
        wd.input[i] = i;
        wd.result[i] = 0;
        workerThreads[i] = std::thread(workerFunc, &wd, i);
    }
    // Wait for the worker threads to finish unless they already have
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(wd.mutex);
    wd.cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return wd.complete; });
    // Consume result of calculations
    for (int i = 0; i < N_WORKERS; i++)
        std::cout << wd.input[i] << "^2 = " << wd.result[i] << std::endl;
    
    for (std::thread& t : workerThreads)
        t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "There is a race condition as the notification can be raised between wd.remainingWorkers.load() > 0) and wd.cv.wait(lock);"

Are you sure that really can happen?
For it to be possible to enter the while loop, the worker must not have decremented the counter yet. The waiting thread is holding the mutex since _before_ the while loop. So until the cv.wait() is entered (where the mutex is released), the worker thread can only decrement the counter, it will be blocked by the mutex from notifying the condition variable until the waiter thread has released the mutex in cv.wait()

Comment: In my mind, moving the decrement earlier (before locking the mutex) can only give the effect that it is more likely for the counter to be 0 when checking it in the if or the while loop of the waiting thread. That if that happens, it will never call cv.wait() and it wont matter when the worker notifies.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, Just a comment with embedded code...

---

I said,

> if each [producer thread] only keeps the mutex locked just long enough to decrement the counter, then the chance of any of them finding the mutex locked is extremely small.

You replied,

> @SolomonSlow a small chance repeated enough times will happen. In the situation I am looking at, this pattern occurs several hundreds of times per second,...

So, I tried this on my 2020 Apple Mac Mini, (Apple clang version 14.0.3)

```c++
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::microseconds;

static std::mutex mx;
volatile long count_a = 1000000;
//static long count_b = 1000000;

static void make_a_thread() {
    std::thread t([](){
        mx.lock();
        std::cout << "ho!\n";
        mx.unlock();
    });
    t.join();
}

static void gopher_it() {
    while (count_a > 0) {
        count_a -= 1;
//      mx.lock();
//      count_b -= 1;
//      mx.unlock();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "yo!\n";
    
    make_a_thread();

    auto t_begin = steady_clock::now();
    gopher_it();
    auto t_end = steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t_end - t_begin);
    std::cout << "that took " << duration.count() << ".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It printed,

```
g++ -std=c++17 -g -o bizzy bizzy.cpp && ./bizzy && ./bizzy && ./bizzy && ./bizzy && ./bizzy
yo!
ho!
that took 3032.
yo!
ho!
that took 3702.
yo!
ho!
that took 3669.
yo!
ho!
that took 3423.
yo!
ho!
that took 3193.
```

Then, I uncommented the four commented-out lines, and I ran it again:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -g -o wizzy wizzy.cpp && ./wizzy && ./wizzy && ./wizzy && ./wizzy && ./wizzy
yo!
ho!
that took 21606.
yo!
ho!
that took 17846.
yo!
ho!
that took 14029.
yo!
ho!
that took 11837.
yo!
ho!
that took 10497.
```

I calculate that my code, on average, took less than 12 nanoseconds, to lock an uncontested lock, decrement a variable, and unlock the lock.

You said, "...hundreds of times per second..." Let's make that, for sake of argument, 600 times per second. That would be 1.67 million nanoseconds per iteration. If any one thread has the lock locked for 12 nanoseconds out of 1.67 million, that's about 0.00072 percent of the time.

IMO, that's a pretty small fraction.

Comment: `make_a_thread` does `t.join();` before returning, so only one thread is ever active at a time in your program.  Is that thread + printing code there just to stop the compiler from optimizing away the locking in a single-threaded program?

Comment: Also note that this isn't just an uncontended lock, it's one that was last held by this thread, so the cache lines (for mutex and `count_b`) is/are already in MESI Modified state, no inter-core communication necessary.  Things are still *pretty* good for a lock that's available on the first try but which requires the CPU to do a read-for-ownership to store.  12 nanoseconds is maybe 40 clock cycles; getting cache that are dirty on another core might be more like 100 to 400.  Still a small fraction of the time for testing to hit the race window, which I think is your point?

Comment: Aside from earlier points, even though i'd like to avoid unnecessary uncontested locks, what I am mostly concerned about is _contested_ ones. Contested locks can cause threads to yield and cause longer delays that depends on scheduling.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Yes. Exactly. I wanted to make sure that the mutex had been used in more than one thread. I don't know about C++, but I remember reading somewhere that the Java Runtime Environment doesn't really initialize a mutex until it has been used by more than one thread.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  In Linux/glibc, that optimization is only done statically, whether you link with `-pthread` or not, IIRC, but a dummy thread makes sure.  You forgot to enable optimization for your benchmark, probably shrinking the performance delta between locking and no locking. Also, note that Apple M1 has I think some of the cheapest atomic RMWs out of most modern ISAs, so the overhead of lock/unlock is cheaper than on other systems. (@Morgan, yes, you definitely want to avoid locking in the common case if you can without introducing other contention or worse overhead there or elsewhere.)